# Sympy TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational when using sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I'm learning `SymPy` now. Here is the problem I got:

```
x = symbols('x',real=True)
h = symbols('h',real=True)
f = symbols('f',cls=Function)    
sym_dexpr = f_diff.subs(f(x), x*exp(-x**2)).doit()
f_diff = f(x).diff(x,1)
expr_diff = as_finite_diff(f_diff, [x, x-h,x-2*h,x-3*h])
w=Wild('w')
c=Wild('c')
patterns = [arg.match(c*f(w)) for arg in expr_diff.args]
coefficients = [t[c] for t in sorted(patterns, key=lambda t:t[w])]
print(coefficients)
```

But I got following **error**:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 coefficients = [t[c] for t in sorted(patterns, key=lambda t:t[w])]
>         2 print(coefficients)
>
> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py
>   in **nonzero**(self)
>       193 
>       194     def **nonzero**(self):
>   --> 195         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
>       196 
>       197     **bool** = **nonzero**
>
> **TypeError**: cannot determine truth value of Relational

I am using `Windows 7`, `Python 3.5.2` and `Anaconda 3`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the sort you perform on `patterns`.

`sorted(patterns, key=lambda t:t[w])` attempts to return `patterns` sorted by every item's value for the key `w`, yet these values can not be compared with each other.

Why is that? because they are "relational" values, means they depend on the values of the variable in them. Lets check:

```
>>> [t[w] for t in patterns]
[-h + x, -3*h + x, -2*h + x, x]
```

Is `-h + x` greater than `-3*h + x` or the other way around? well, that depends on what `h` and `x` are, and since SymPy can't determine the order of these values, you get an error.