# Derivative and how to convert symbolic expression of it

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I need to obtain a derivative to use it later in numerical calculations. And my code doesn't work at all. I tried to use lambdify but the error is "can't convert symbols int". I read other answers for similar questions but it still doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp as bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import genlaguerre as L
from scipy.special import gamma as G
from math import factorial
from math import sqrt
import sympy as sym
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify


mp = 938.2720813
mn = 939.5654133

mu = (mn + mp)/4

hbar = 197.3270533

h2m = hbar**2/(2*mu)

V0 = 20
Rv = 1.5

Q0 = 1.5
Rq = 4.5

EIm = 0.3
ERe = 1

V = lambda r : -V0*np.exp(-r/Rv)
Q = lambda r : -Q0*np.exp(-r/Rq)


chi = lambda r, l : sqrt(factorial(l)*beta**3/(G(3 + l))) * r * L(l,2)(beta * r) * np.exp(- beta * r / 2)

r, l, beta = sym.symbols('r, l, beta')

def chifD(r, l, beta):
    return sqrt(factorial(l)*beta**3/(G(3 + l))) * r * L(l,2)(beta * r) * np.exp(- beta * r / 2)

def chiD(r, l, beta):
    return sym.diff(chifD(r ,l, beta), r)

print(chiD(r, l, beta))

chiLambdified = lambdify(((r,l, beta),),chiD(r,l, beta),"numpy")

print(chiD(1, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're mixing modules you shouldn't. I kept modifying your chi function until I got something that works. Nothing short of removing all `math` and `scipy` functions returned something that wasn't a `TypeError`.

```py
# works with sympy sqrt.
chi = lambda r, l : sym.sqrt(l*r)
print(chi(r,l))

# doesn't work with math or numpy sqrt.
chi = lambda r, l : math.sqrt(l*r)
print(chi(r,l))
```

If you want to use functions, you'll have to use the ones that come with sympy, define your own using basic operators (so that sympy objects will be accepted) or find simpler ways to define your operations: sqrt() can simply be substituted by **(1/2).

Maybe you should look for a way that can make sympy accept functions from other modules because writing all of the special functions from scipy yourself looks like it will be a pain.

Comment: It seems that scipy, numpy and math functions are exclusively numeric functions which do not accept symbolic expressions, which is why sympy has it's own set of equivalent functions. There is probably a line in their definitions that goes something like: ```ìf input != float or input != int; raise TypeError```

Comment: Thank you, at least now I understand where is the problem. But i certainly need to find a way to use special fuctions from scipy here.

Comment: Seems like there are sympy functions for factorial and gamma, but even those do not handle symbolic expressions. Is it really necessary to handle everything symbolically? Because I think there's a reason sympy doesn't have those functions as symbolic handlers. https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/gamma.html#gamma

Comment: Yes I  have already found gamma and factorial, fixed it and obtained new error. 
"cannot determine truth value of relational"

Comment: I'm not sure that it's necessary to use symbolic calculations, I just thought that it had to be easiest way, because usually it isn't a problem to obtain the derivative of this function symbolically.

Comment: I can't see your code and you shouldn't discuss follow up questions in one thread as far as I know. Anyways, I'd try to determine where your code does boolean checks. If it doesn't, find out which function you use does the boolean check internally and at which point. Probably something in the lambda functions.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823004/sympy-typeerror-cannot-determine-truth-value-of-relational-when-using-sympy
Btw I'd like it if you accepted my answer because I need that 50 rep to finally be able to post images and comment on other peoples posts :D