# Finding common elements between 2 lists regardless of order- python 2

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Id like to figure out a way to find all the similar elements from 2 different lists

The two list are as fallows,

```
A=[[[a1, b1],
  [a2, b2],
  [a3, b3]],
 [[a1, b2],
  [a2, b1],
  [a3, b3]],
 [[a1, b1],
  [a3, b2],
  [a2, b3]]]

B=[[[a1, b1],
  [a3, b3],
  [a2, b2]],
 [[a1, b2],
  [a2, b1],
  [a3, b3]],
 [[a1, b1],
  [a3, b2],
  [a2, b3]]]
```

Id consider the first elements of each list to be duplicates 
`[[a1, b1],[a2, b2], [a3, b3]]` and 
`[[a1, b1],[a3, b3], [a2, b2]]` to be duplicates.

The output Im looking for would be a list of either one of the common elements in a separate list as such,

```
C=[[a1, b1],[a2, b2], [a3, b3]]
```

Ive been working with this code, but it doesn't recognize they first two elements as duplicate and I'm wondering what I should add to account for it.

```
C=[ i for i in A if i in B]
```

Comment: Achieve this in one line with nested list comprehension and zip: `[[item_a for item_a in a_list if item_a in b_list] for a_list, b_list in zip(A, B)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare for *identical sublists* regardless of order, one way is using `zip` and `map` by sorting each sublist first:

```
l1 = [[['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2'], ['a3', 'b3']],
      [['a1', 'b2'], ['a2', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b3']],
      [['a1', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b2'], ['a2', 'b3']]]
l2 = [[['a1', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b3'], ['a2', 'b2']],
      [['a1', 'b2'], ['a2', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b3']],
      [['a1', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b2'], ['a2', 'b4']]]

                              # sort the sublists first          # check if the sorted lists are equal        
result = [x for x, y in zip(*(map(sorted, l) for l in (l1, l2))) if x == y]
```

**Identical Sublists** Result:

```
[[['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2'], ['a3', 'b3']],
 [['a1', 'b2'], ['a2', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b3']]]
```

Update: Since you are using `sympy` and experiences an error, it's likely it happened on the [`sorted` function per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823004/sympy-typeerror-cannot-determine-truth-value-of-relational-when-using-sympy).  Try this solution instead:

```
                                       # check if all items in x are also part of y
result = [x for x, y in zip(l1, l2) if all(subx in y for subx in x)]
```

---

If you are only concerned about getting the *common elements* within each sublist, here is another way:

```
          # check for common elements, put them in a list and return
result = [[sub_x for sub_x in x if sub_x in y] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

**Common Elements** Result:

```
[[['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2'], ['a3', 'b3']],
 [['a1', 'b2'], ['a2', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b3']],
 [['a1', 'b1'], ['a3', 'b2']]]
```

Comment: Hey this is great as well! I'm trying to use this on another 2 lists and its giving out an error 'cannot determine truth value of Relational'. Im thinking it has something to do with the fact that Ive defined a1, a2, b1 etc as symbols in sympy, rather then strings. Would doing that mess with the code you've provided here?

Comment: I'm not a `sympy` user, but is there a way to test for equality on the objects? If so I'd replace the `x == y` part with that test, e.g. `if all(sympy.eq(x1, y1) for x1, y1 in zip(x, y))`

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll try to see if theres any way around it

Comment: It looks like the issue is from the `sorted` function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823004/sympy-typeerror-cannot-determine-truth-value-of-relational-when-using-sympy.  In that case, would need a different approach.  I have updated the answer, see if it helps.

Comment: You have been so incredibly helpful, thank you very much. The code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

## For Unordered Unique Element Containers, Try Python Sets!

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set

Python Sets model mathematical sets in the sense that they are unordered containers of unique elements. It is not completely clear from your question exactly what you are considering to be duplicates. You may have to create sets of sets, but note than in order to have sets containing sets, you must use frozen_sets. The python documentation does a good job of describing these.

So your new code may look something like

```py
A = set([frozen_set((a1,b1),
(a2. b2),
(a3, b3))
frozen_set((a1, b2),
(a1, b1),
(a3, b3))
... # And so on
```

**NOTE:** The internal lists were converted to tuples in order to be a hashable type

Again, the exact implementation of sets and frozen_sets depends on *which* elements you consider order and uniqueness to matter.

## Set intersections

Once you have your set data structures correctly written, you can find all common elements with a set intersection.

```py
C = A & B
```

It is equivalent to a mathematical set intersection.

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: The question's type is `list`, not `tuple`.  If they need to be changed to `tuple` for your answer to work, the object conversion should be part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
A=[[["a1", "b1"],
  ["a2", "b2"],
  ["a3", "b3"]],
 [["a1", "b2"],
  ["a2", "b1"],
  ["a3", "b3"]],
 [["a1", "b1"],
  ["a3", "b2"],
  ["a2", "b3"]]]

B=[[["a1", "b1"],
  ["a3", "b3"],
  ["a2", "b2"]],
 [["a1", "b2"],
  ["a2", "b1"],
  ["a3", "b3"]],
 [["a1", "b1"],
  ["a3", "b2"],
  ["a2", "b4"]]]
ans=[]
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        for i1 in i:
            if i1 not in j:
                break
        else:
            ans.append(i)
            break
print ans
```

You can try something like this.

Comment: This works perfectly ! Can I just ask a bit about the code, as I'm not 100% sure how everything works. So Im guessing the first few lines are comparing the elements in between A and B but what is the i1 referring to? Is it like i[1]?

Comment: @Asiv yes `i1` is elements of `i` i.e `["a1", "b1"]`

Comment: Ok so the code is checking if i1 is in any of the j elements in B, and if it is we add the i into the ans list. Im just confused as to how this recognizes the element as 'duplicates'  even if the order is different

Comment: `if i1 not in j` here i1 is `["a1", "b1"]` and j is `[["a1", "b1"],
  ["a3", "b3"],
  ["a2", "b2"]]` .So order does not matter.

Comment: Ohh I see. Again, perfect! Thank you very much for the help