# How to solve this math: TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Tags: python

How can I solve the integrated math with Python?

[image: a double integrate math]

Here is my code:

```
import scipy.integrate 
import sympy as sp
import math 
x= sp.Symbol('x')
y= sp.Symbol('y')
f= lambda x,y: sp.exp(sp.cos(3*x**2-2*y))+(sp.sin(5*x**2+3*x*y**4))/sp.ln(x*y**3+5*y**5)-sp.tan(7*y*x**3+2*x*y)
g= lambda x:0 
h= lambda x:2 
i, e = scipy.integrate.dblquad(f,x,sp.sqrt(x**2+5),g,h) #error line
i
```

Error:

> TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Image:

[image: Error]

Comment: Do you understand what the error means? Have you searched for anything about it? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46830147/6273251) explains why the error was happening to someone in a specific case; does that info help you at all?

Comment: So sorry but i'm a newbie with python, can you explain more to me? The sympy method can't use like that but i don't know how to fix it because my teacher doesn't teach me about the sympy method and the others method ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sympy TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational when using sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823004/sympy-typeerror-cannot-determine-truth-value-of-relational-when-using-sympy)