# Why does sympy.Min cause a TypeError?

Tags: python, math, sympy, minimum

The following minimalistic script crashes with SymPy 1.12 and Python 3.11:

```
import sympy as sp

u, v = sp.symbols("u v")
sp.Min(u**1.0*v, v**1.0*u)
```

The result is a `TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational`. I have this situation arising implicitly in a general framework, so just dropping the (here) unnecessary minimum or the **1.0 is not feasible for me. Using something implicit to simplify the expression would be fine, but for example calling `sp.simplify` on the first or second argument doesn't succeed at simplifying the expression.

Comment: As an aside, `1.0` is a float, and thus imprecise by definition.  Sympy tries to work with exact symbolic expressions and usually handles floats very unintuitively.

Answer (score 0):

Sympy.Min is a [Relational](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.relational) type. Meaning it evaluates the relation between `u**1.0*v`==`uv` and `v**1.0*u`==`vu`==`uv`. And since both of those expressions essentially are the same thing, it can't evaluate (i.e. It is not of the correct type). Put simply, it's like comparing x to x itself.

What you need to do here is simply something like `sp.Min(u**(1.0*v), v**(1.0*u))` (if this is what you wanted).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823004/sympy-typeerror-cannot-determine-truth-value-of-relational-when-using-sympy) also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full error message.  Yes, sympy does show a lot of intermediate steps, but often it's worth paying attention to it - all the way to the end.

```
In [212]: Min(u**1.0*v, v**1.0*u)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[212], line 1
----> 1 Min(u**1.0*v, v**1.0*u)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/functions/elementary/miscellaneous.py:394, in MinMaxBase.__new__(cls, *args, **assumptions)
    392     return cls.zero
    393 # remove redundant args that are easily identified
--> 394 args = cls._collapse_arguments(args, **assumptions)
    395 # find local zeros
    396 args = cls._find_localzeros(args, **assumptions)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/functions/elementary/miscellaneous.py:436, in MinMaxBase._collapse_arguments(cls, args, **assumptions)
    434 if not args:
    435     return args
--> 436 args = list(ordered(args))
    437 if cls == Min:
    438     other = Max

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/sorting.py:309, in ordered(seq, keys, default, warn)
    306         if len(u) > 1:
    307             raise ValueError(
    308                 'not enough keys to break ties: %s' % u)
--> 309 yield from value

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/sorting.py:309, in ordered(seq, keys, default, warn)
    306         if len(u) > 1:
    307             raise ValueError(
    308                 'not enough keys to break ties: %s' % u)
--> 309 yield from value

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/sorting.py:297, in ordered(seq, keys, default, warn)
    294         raise ValueError('if default=False then keys must be provided')
    295     d[None].extend(seq)
--> 297 for k, value in sorted(d.items()):
    298     if len(value) > 1:
    299         if keys:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py:510, in Relational.__bool__(self)
    509 def __bool__(self):
--> 510     raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

It's trying to order/sort the arguments, and to do that it has to determine which is smaller than the other, e.g. `bool(a<b)`.

With numpy arrays we often see SO questions about a `ambiguity error`, when the poster tries to compare 2 arrays, and does so in a context that expects just one True/False value.  This is the sympy equivalent - comparing the size of 2 or more expressions.

In some cases `Min` is returned unevaluated, awaiting more specific values

```
In [213]: Min(u**1.0*v, 0)
Out[213]: Min(0, u**1.0*v)
In [214]: Min(u**1.0*v, 0).subs({u:1, v:-1})
Out[214]: -1
```

Just tweaking the float value in your arguments does that:

```
In [215]: Min(u**1.0*v, v**2.0*u)
Out[215]: Min(u**1.0*v, u*v**2.0)
In [217]: Min(u**1*v, v**1*u)
Out[217]: u⋅v
```

I don't know why the use of 1.0 raises the error; but often in sympy, the use of floats does force a different evaluation route.

Comment: The float issue is a bug. There is an open PR to fix it: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/25262